# Undefined index: und

Tags: entities

I have created a custom profile field called "field_protection". I am using the following code to reference that field but am getting error:

**Notice: Undefined index: und**

```
$is_protected = 0;
   $is_protected  = (int)$act->field_protection['und']['0']['value'];
    if ($is_protected == 1) {
      form_set_error('from', t("Protected !!!"));
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like $act->field_protection does not have a 'und' key. Also, the constant 'LANGUAGE_NONE' can be used instead of 'und'. Use the devel module to call a dpm() on $act->field_protection to see it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [EntityAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module for working with fields. You don't need to worry about some key exists or not. here is an example:

```
$entityWrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('ENTITY_TYPE (eg. node, user..)', ENTITY_KEY_OR_ENTITY);

$protectionFieldValue = $entityWrapper->field_protection->value();

if (null != $protectionFieldValue /* put your condition */) {
  form_set_error('from', t("Protected !!!"));
  return;
}
```

or here is a way without an EntityAPI:

```
if (isset($act->field_protection['und']) && ($is_protected  = (int)$act->field_protection['und']['0']['value'])) {
    if ($is_protected == 1) {
      form_set_error('from', t("Protected !!!"));
      return;
    }
}
```